# How to compare 2 different excel workbook columns using only pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 different excels as follows:
Excel 1 (Df1.xlsx):

[image]

Excel 2 (Df2.xlsx):

[image]

I want to search records which match of DF1 to DF2, output should come in another third Dataframe Df3 as follows:

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: [edit] the question and paste the data as text. [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Why `2, 444221` is in the desired output, if this record is not on  `df1` ?

Comment: `df3 = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Ticket Number': 'Trouble'}), on='Trouble')` should do the job